# Migrate Solr index to Datastax (Enterprise Search)?

Tags: solr, lucene, datastax-enterprise

I'm having an index (Solr/Lucene v. 4.x) with ~1bn rows (180gb) and wanted to migrate that into the Datastax variant of Solr. I couldn't find any HOWTO or migration guideline. Will simply copying the index dir to Datastax solr.data// do the trick, plus posting the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml?

br

accid

Answer (score 1):

The first question is how much of your data is "stored", and then you need to export your existing Solr data to, say, CSV files, and then import that data into Datastax Enterprise.

But, you cannot directly move a Lucene/Solr index into Datastax Enterprise. For one thing, DSE stores some additional attributes for each Solr document.

The whole point of DSE is that Cassandra becomes your system of record, maintaining the raw data, and then DSE/Solr is simply indexing the data to support rich query. DSE uses Cassandra to store the data and Solr to index the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like, https://github.com/dbashford/solr2solr, to copy your data from one to the other, but you can't re-use your index files.